# passing argument 1 of 'setBackgroundColor:' from incompatible pointer type

Tags: ios, quartz-graphics, layer

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code.

    // BackgroundColor
    CALayer *myLayer = [self layer];    
    [myLayer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5].CGColor];
    ...
}
```

when I want to setBackgroundColor for the layer, the warning occurred.
But the code runs OK.

===========================================================

The Best Answer is :
`#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Answer (score 4):

If you don't include Quartz in your module then the compiler does not know about CGColor as a type and issues the warning.

Put `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in your header and it should remove the warning.

Hope this helps,

Dave

Comment: Magic: good catch! @user754223: click that little check next to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `backgroundColor` property of `CALayer` is of type `CGColorRef` which is the return type of the `CGColor` property of `UIColor`, so the code looks sound.

Try doing this instead:

```
[myLayer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5] CGColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove CGColor conversion from the command and write it as:

```
[myLayer setBackgroundColor:(id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5].CGColor];
```

sorry...try this updated version